# pass data from popup to injected script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension, in this i injected injected.js into web page using content script. In injected.js i have one button, when we click on this button i'll open a popup window(window.open) with inner html file, now i want to send data from the popup to injected script

popup.html

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
        <input id="mybutton" type="button" value="click" />
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js">

  </script>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
window.onload = function(){
var button = document.getElementById('mybutton');
button.onclick = function() {
  showAlert();
};
};

function showAlert(){
var evt=document.createEvent("CustomEvent");
evt.initCustomEvent("yourCustomEvent", true, true, "Data");
document.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

injected.js

```
$('.aic').append('<div id="sendButtonID" class="sendButtonCls" role="button" tabindex="0" gh="cm" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">Send Now</div></div>');
$('#sendButtonID').click(function(){
window.open(popupURL, '', 'height=400,width=500');
  //console.log('chrome: ',chrome);
});

document.addEventListener('yourCustomEvent', function (e)
{
 console.log('2');

 console.log("received "+e);
});
```

Comment: there is no point in creating custom event in your popup.js

Comment: Then what to do in this case..?

Comment: You dont need injected.js for appending elements and listening to click events. Just use content script for that

Comment: Just use content script to append button and listen to click events. Then use message passing between content script and popup to communicate

Comment: @BharathKumar, injected page-scripts are only needed to access the javascript *variables* of the webpage. Do you need it?

Comment: I'm using gmail api https://github.com/KartikTalwar/gmail.js/tree/master. and my content script is loading before gmail page so at that time my button is not appending to gmail

Comment: You can use "run_at" : "document_end"

Comment: yeah i used in my manifest but not appending

Comment: @BharathKumar, because the gmail site scripts build the actual page after the `document_end` occurs like many sites do. Use `waitForKeyElements` script or manually check in `setInterval` function or, in case you want to add the button without any visual delay after its container element appears, `MutationObserver`.

Comment: But in this case i was unable to use gamil api  https://github.com/KartikTalwar/gmail.js/tree/master, from content script

Comment: Add the waiting code in the injected script then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass data from popup script to injected you can pass like this, first you should pass from popup script to content script then from content script to injected script